# How can I export a variable from whithin a while loop runing in the background in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a bash script that checks for system updates every 10 minutes in my Arch Linux system using the yay package manager. For other purposes I need to run the while loop in the background and to export the `updates` variable to use it elsewhere within the same script. Everything works, except that the variable is not exported.

```
#!/bin/sh

updates=''

while true; do
  updates=$(ping -q -c 1 -W 1 ping.eu > /dev/null && yay -Qu | wc -l)
  export updates
  sleep 600
done &

echo $updates
```

Comment: What value would you expect the variable to have when it is repeatedly assigned to in a loop? I suggest to [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: Environment variables can be passed from the parent process to the child process when the child is started. The parent does not see any modifications done by the child.

Comment: You mention bash but the shebang says sh. Which is it?

Comment: Running the loop in the background makes it run in a separate process (a subshell), and separate processes cannot affect each other's variables. That's not what `export` does, and nothing else does it either because it's impossible. You need to use a file (or pipe) to communicate between the processes.

Comment: Thank you for you comments everyone. That answers the question directly @GordonDavisson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes can't directly read variables set in child processes, so you need a different way to communicate the `updates` value.  One option is to use a temporary file:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '' >updates.txt

while true; do
    ping -q -c 1 -W 1 ping.eu > /dev/null && yay -Qu | wc -l >updates.txt
    sleep 600
done &

# [Do stuff]
# ...

updates=$(cat updates.txt)
printf '%s\n' "$updates"
```

Comment: This was my first approach. I wanted to avoided it but since processes can't directly read variables set in child processes this is actually the only possible solution I see. Thank you for your contribution.